# Ajax call in UIWebView returns errors

Tags: ios, ajax, asp.net-mvc, uiwebview

I have a mobile website that is loaded in a UIWebView that has a problem with an ajax call returning error.  If I load the site in a full browser the ajax returns success, if I load it in a mobile browser (safari), it also works correctly.

When it loads in the UIWebView, the ajax call works but it fires the Error callback instead of success even though all the server code was executed correctly.

Anyone run into the same issue?

Sample Code:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "/Mobile/MVCMethod",
        data: { data: JSON.stringify(model) },

        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",  // tried all 'text','json','jsonp'
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

           alert("success") // works in full browser and mobile browser


        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            alert("error") // gets called in UIWebView ios
        }
    });
```

Comment: Same problem here. Ever solved it?